# How to use two Split() functions in each other in classic ASP?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, vbscript, asp-classic

I have two variables (`getYear` and `getBranch`) in my page.

```
getYear-1,4,11
getBranch-4,5,7

GetYearSingle = Split(getYear, ",")
```

I get single array value after `Split()` function like this:

```
For Each iLoop In GetYearSingle
  response.write "<br>Year= " & iLoop
Next
```

I get result like this

```
year=1
year=4
year=11
```

but I need result like this

```
year=1
Branch=4

year=4
Branch=5

year=11
Branch=7
```

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb I'll assume that

```
getYear-1,4,11
getBranch-4,5,7
```

was actually meant to look like this:

```
getYear = "1,4,11"
getBranch = "4,5,7"
```

If that's the case you want to split both strings at commas and use a `For` loop (not a `For Each` loop) to iterate over the elements of both arrays.

```
arrYear   = Split(getYear, ",")
arrBranch = Split(getBranch, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(arrYear)
  response.write "<br>Year= " & arrYear(i)
  response.write "<br>Branch= " & arrBranch(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over **both** arrays via the (syncronized) index:

```
Option Explicit

Dim y : y = Split("1,4,11", ",")
Dim b : b = Split("4,5,7", ",")
If UBound(y) = UBound(b) Then
   Dim i
   For i = 0 To UBound(y)
       WScript.Echo y(i), b(i)
   Next
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 44118915.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host, Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

1 4
4 5
11 7
```